# Google Cloud Api Authorization

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to use google cloud pub sub to implement Facebook kind of notifications in  blog application which has following architecture

I have a both web and android device as a client for rest services exposed.
Those rest services has been secured using OAuth2 (spring security).

When user create a blog then if someone comment on that post, the concern owner can get the notifications. Only authorized user can create a post or comment and the concern person can see the notifications

**I don't want user to authorize again with Google** so how I can incorporate the api's in my architecture using pull notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically wouldn't use Google Cloud Pub/Sub in the client in the type of setup you describe. Cloud Pub/Sub isn't designed to scale to a number of subscriptions that are on the order of number of phones.  Instead, you'd want to use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/). Firebase has a model that handles registration of devices to receive messages that is more in line with what you are thinking of, e.g., [Set Up a Firebase Cloud Messaging Client App on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) and 
[Implementing a Firebase Cloud Messaging Client on Chrome](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/chrome/client)

What you may use Cloud Pub/Sub for is communication between different services. For example, perhaps the service that handles blog posts publishes messages on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic that your notification service subscribes to. The notification service would process the message and send out Firebase Cloud Messaging messages to end users as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but in case if Firebase cloud messaging the issue is that it is only supported in chrome browser, not in other while the google cloud pub sub is rest based hence no browser dependency will be there. Kindly suggest